# Windows tips and tricks link?

Tags: discussion

There was a post here  ( I dont remember where exactly) - a closed post which got many votes -  where everyone wrote their favorite win7 command , or cmd commands

how can i find it ?

Comment: http://www.stackprinter.com/ maybe?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a prime candidate for deletion according to current moderation policy, as it's both *subjective* and *polling*. So it's probably been (soft-)deleted. In that case, nobody can search for it, and only users with more than 10,000 reputation points can access the question, given its URL or a link to it.

If you don't remember anything about the question (like its URL from a bookmark or browser history, or the name of the person who asked), popular questions can be found by searching the "question popularity" badges, like the gold level [Famous Question](https://superuser.com/badges/28/famous-question), [Great Question](https://superuser.com/badges/22/great-question), [Stellar Question](https://superuser.com/badges/34/stellar-question), or the silver level [Favorite Question](https://superuser.com/badges/33/favorite-question), [Good Question](https://superuser.com/badges/21/good-question), or [Notable Question](https://superuser.com/badges/27/notable-question). Some bronze level badges exist as well, but they'll of course produce even longer results lists.

Comment: Interesting that about half of the Stellar Questions and a third of the Great Questions are closed.

Comment: Wait, are you really saying that 10K+ users can't find deleted questions by searching for keywords? Hm.